# What css framework is better between 960gs and Blueprint?

Tags: theming

For a new project what is better for drupal between Blueprint and 960gs?
I usually prefer 960gs, but for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used 960gs, but used to use Blueprint.  Blueprint worked fine if I was always making 960px width templates.  But, now I veer away from those CSS sizers.  They're too constricted in what you can accomplish.  Also, I always prefer to size the CSS with a min-width:960px and max-width:1200px.  So many of the screen res. are 15" and 17" now.  You can't really accomplish much beyond the scope of 960px with Blueprint and, I'm assuming, 960gs.